# iPad Air 2 has shut me out

Tags: ipad

This is a replacement unit, replacing one that I dropped. I have been in the process of transferring my apps to the new iPad. I had finished yesterday and it was working just fine and then it seemed like it just stopped working. When I try to turn it on, I just get a black screen. I can access Siri and Siri answers verbally.  I know my user name and my password, which is coded number and fingerprint access, however I can't bring up a screen to enter it. 
Do you have any suggestions?
It is fully charged and I can turn the power on. Unfortunately the only reason I know it's on is that I can contact Siri but the screen is still black.

Comment: Have you tried to do a hard reset by pressing Home button + lock simultaneously until the Apple logo appears (10 seconds)? (This will not delete any data stored on the device).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely try a hard reset! I had the same issue with my iPhone - it worked fine - music was playing, the Mute Button would vibrate when I switched it to mute - but it had the slightly annoying fail that the screen was just black. A hard reset did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, try performing a hard reset. You can do so by holding the home button (with TouchID) and the power button for 10 seconds together.

After 10 seconds, your iPad will be turned of. You can now try restarting it with the power button when your iPad doesn't restart automatically.